# App Transport Security sometimes rejected valid HTTPS server

Tags: ssl, ios9, afnetworking, nsapptransportsecurity

I'm facing a pain in the ass described as follow:

- My iOS app is defined to connect to our company's server, which is a HTTPS one that satisfies all the requirements needed by iOS9's App Transport Security Policy
- The app works well with most users
- But sometimes there's some users/devices cannot connect due to a -1022 error saying that ATS has rejected our HTTPS server as it's a cleartext server (?!)
- After deleting then reinstalling exactly the same build, those users/devices can connect to our server seamlessly

So is there anyone ever encountered the same problem? Can anyone please help troubleshoot the issue?

Note: I strongly against adding my domain the the plist nor using nsallowsarbitraryloads because our server's ssl certificate is strictly valid and satisfy the requirements.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two scenarios where this could happen:

- Your App is trying to access some specific page or link over HTTP (even tho the server supports HTTPS); you could perhaps search for http:// URLs within your code.
- There is a specific page or URL on the server that is redirecting clients (such as your App) to HTTP, from HTTPS.